# Converting passed in String to Vertex for DirectedGraph

Tags: java, parsing, data-structures, directed-graph

Having some trouble with creating vertices and using them in a Directed Graph.

I have two classes to be concerned with: Node.java and Digraph.java

```
  public class Node {
   private final int vertex;
   private HashSet<Node> outgoingEdges;

   public Node(int index) {
    this.index = index;
  }

  protected void addOutgoing(Node start) {
    outgoingEdges.add(start);
}

 public class Digraph {
 private Set<Node> vertices;

 public Digraph(String str) {
 String eliminatePrefix = str.replaceAll("a", "");
 for (int i = 0; i < eliminatePrefix.length; i++) {
     // Not sure how to proceed
     // 
 }

 protected void add(Node a, Node b) {
     a.addOutgoing(b);
 }
```

The String being passed in looks something like [a1, a2][a16, a10]....
a1 and a2 are vertices. The pairing means there's a directed route from a1 to a2. The Strings need to be parsed and converted, I know, and once they are properly formatted, the addEdge method will be called. I am just trying to figure out this constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the cleanest way to do it but it works

```
        String s = "[a1, a2][a3, a4][a5, a6]";

    s = s.replaceAll("[a\\s\\[]", ""); // remove " " "[" and ","
    String[] edges = s.split("]"); // split the string into substrings on ]

    for (String edge : edges) {
        String[] points = edge.split(","); 
        int[] p = new int[2];
        p[0] = Integer.parseInt(points[0]);
        p[1] = Integer.parseInt(points[1]);

        // Construct your edge here
        System.out.println("Edge from: " + p[0] + " to " + p[1]);
    }
```